# TypeError with jest.setMock()

Tags: javascript, jasmine, reactjs, jestjs

I'm wondering why there's a type error when I explicity set a mock for jest.

I do this:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
//tests/app/headernav-test.js
jest.dontMock('../../../app/modules/HeaderNav.jsx');
jest.dontMock('../../TestContext');
jest.setMock('../../../app/modules/LoginStatus.jsx', './mocks/LoginStatus.jsx');

var React = require('react/addons'),
    MyComponent = require('../../../app/modules/HeaderNav.jsx'),
    TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils,
    TestContext = require('./../../TestContext'),
    component = TestContext.getRouterComponent(MyComponent).component;

describe('HeaderNav', function() {

    it('renders the header nav', function() {

    });
});
```

and I get this.

```
TypeError: /home/4m1r/project/tests/app/modules/headernav-test.js: Cannot read property 'TestUtils' of undefined
```

mocks/LoginStatus.jsx is simply this:

```
var React = require.requireActual('react');

var LoginStatus = React.createClass({
    displayName: 'LoginStatus',
    render: function() {

        return (
            <div id="" className="LoginStatus">
                <div className="login-status-box">

                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});


module.exports = LoginStatus;
```

Here's the Jest documentation: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/api.html#jest-setmock-modulename-moduleexports

Comment: Just a guess, but does `jest.dontMock('react/addons')` fix it?

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand same deal.  I haven't had to mock the addons for any other tests.